# scrlayer-scrpage package option list

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I have been using `scrpage2` for more than 10 years. Since it is obsolete, I want to switch to the newer `scrlayer-scrpage` package.

The documentation however does not seem to list the package options, it only contains several examples.

```
\usepackage[%
%%% Lines
   % headtopline,
   % plainheadtopline,
   % headsepline,
   % plainheadsepline,
   % footsepline,
   % plainfootsepline,
   % footbotline,
   % plainfootbotline,
   % ilines,
   % clines,
   % olines,
% column titles (content, style)
   automark,
   % autooneside,% ignore optional argument in automark at oneside
   komastyle,
   % standardstyle,
   % markuppercase,
   % markusedcase,
   nouppercase,
]{scrpage2}
```

Only from the log messages

> ```
> Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: You've used obsolete option `komastyle'.
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                Usage of this option is deprecated.
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                You should simply replace `komastyle'
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                by `pagestyleset=KOMA-Script'.
> ```

I could figure out these changes

- `komastyle` -> `pagestyleset=KOMA-Script`
- `nouppercase` -> `markcase=ignoreuppercase`

How can I gather the complete list?
If it is in the manual, which section or page?

EDIT: 
I have further problems to set up the options. I could not find an example in the documentation for this:

```
\setheadsepline{.4pt}[\color{black}] % configures the line below the header
```

Is according to the log not valid anymore

> ```
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                You should use KOMA-Script options
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                `headsepline', `headtopline', `footsepline',
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                or `footbotline' with values
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                `<line thickness>:<line length>' to setup
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                the line length and thickness, and
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                `\setkomafont' or `\addtokomafont' to
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                setup the colour on input line 74.
> ```

An example for this would help.

Comment: The German scrguide has a section "18.5. Das obsolete Erbe von scrpage2", at which's end the following note can be found: "Im KOMA-Script-Buch [Koh18a] finden sich an dieser Stelle weitere Informationen." (English translations: "18.5 The obsolete heritage of scrpage2" and "More information can be found In the KOMA-Script-book [Koh18a].")

Comment: Correct. But this section does not answer any of my questions.

Comment: See chapter  »5. Headers and Footers with scrlayer-scrpage« for the options of `scrlayer-scrpage`; especially sections »5.4. Using Predefined Page Styles« and »5.5. Manipulating Page Styles«. The options are using a key-value-syntax.

Comment: Note that `scrlayer-scrpage` sets `autooneside=true` by default.

Comment: Your question: "How can I gather the complete list?". My answer: Maybe it can be found in the KOMA-script-book, the guide does suggest this could be true.

Comment: @Skillmon No, there is no list or table with all options. And also in section 18.5 there are only some depreciated commads mentioned. In the book and in the documentation is an index of all class and package options.

Comment: Chapter 5 shows the options and macros in blue(documentation) or gray(book) boxes followed by their explanation.

Comment: Replace `\setheadsepline{.4pt}[\color{black}]` by option `headsepline=.4pt` and `\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{black}}`

Comment: I understand that the blue lines are options. But I do not know if these are package options or can also be set later. Also I would like to see examples to understand them. On page 259 there is `headwidth=width :offset :offset`. I am using `\setheadwidth[0pt]{text}` . I do not know how to use the documentation code. And my code is not documented anymore.

Comment: The package options can also be set later using `\KOMAoption` or `\KOMAoptions`. If the values for the keys are macros, lengths or counters it is suggested to use `\KOMAoption` or `\KOMAoptions`.  You could use  `\KOMAoptions{headwidth=text:0pt}`.  Maybe you have to ask own question for  each option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In chapter 5 »Headers and Footers with scrlayer-scrpage« all the macros and options are explained.

The headsepline can be configured by option `headsepline=<thickness>:<lenghth>`. You can omit the values. Default `thickness` is `0.4pt`, default `length` is the symbolic value `head`.

`\KOMAoptions{headsepline}` -> head sepline with thickness 0.4pt and width of the head as length

`\KOMAoptions{headsepline=1pt}` -> head sepline with thickness 1pt and width of the head as length

`\KOMAoptions{headsepline=:10cm}` -> head sepline with default thickness and length 10cm

`\KOMAoptions{headsepline=1pt:10cm}` -> head sepline with thickness 1pt and length 10cm

`headsepline` can be used as package option. But if the values of the key are macros, lengths or counters it is recommended to use \KOMAoption or \KOMAoptions.

To change the alignment of the `headsepline` with the head you can use one of the options `ilines`, `clines` or `olines` (this is the same as with scrpage2). Default is `ilines`, ie aligned to the inner margin of head.

To set the color of headsepline change the font element `headsepline` using `\addtokomafont` or `setkomafont`.

So you can replace the outdated scrpage2 code `\setheadsepline{.4pt}[\color{black}]` by

```
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=.4pt:head}% .4pt and head are the defaults
\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{black}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=4pt:5cm,olines}
\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{orange}}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is an alpha-version of a command which can be used to get information about the options set in the preamble or by the packages itself for `scrlayer-scrpage` and `scrlayer`.  `scrlayer-scrpage` loads and uses `scrlayer`. See [Abfrage der gesetzten Optionen](https://komascript.de/node/1893) (German).

```
% based on https://komascript.de/node/1893
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\noindent\KOMAScriptVersion\par\bigskip

\minisec{scrlayer-scrpage.sty:}
\KOMAoptionsOf[\url]{scrlayer-scrpage.sty}

\minisec{scrlayer.sty:}
\KOMAoptionsOf[\url]{scrlayer.sty}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]